# Reset to a default if ngModel value no longer in list of dropdown options

Tags: angular

I've got the following Component HTML Code

```
<label class="dropdown-list">
    <select name="objektart" id="ddlPreisBis" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="Filter.PreisMax">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option *ngFor="let obj of PreisBis" [ngValue]="obj.Key">{{ obj.Name }}</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

component.ts

```
PreisBis: Array<KeyNameModel<number>>;
```

Depending on other values, the items in "PreisBis" Array may change. If this happens and the value already selected in "Filter.Preismax" is no longer available in the PreisBis-Array, I want the empty option to be selected.

How can I achieve this? Currently no option is selected and the old selected value is still present in the model.

Comment: how is your ``PreisBis`` fetched ?

Comment: @CruelEngine It is read by subscribing to an Observable (json request).

Comment: have you tried by setting ``Filter.PreisMax = '' `` ?

Comment: That would of course work, but i'm create a huge form with lots of dropdownlists like this one. With this approach i would have to check on every "PreisBis" Load, if the current PreisMax value has its representation in the array and if not reset the value. For 20+dropdowns this does not seem to the best approach

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like,

```
<select class="form-control filter-control">
      <option [value]=undefined>All</option>
      <option value="equals">= Equals</option>
      <option value="similar">Similar</option>
</select>
```

I think you had use wrong. All
because you have to always initiate model value using `model.name = ''`